# Data-driven vertical/horizontal lines in d3

Tags: d3.js, data-driven

I am attempting to draw a series of vertical lines on a d3 chart. The data source for this is a list of x positions (in the data) which is mapped through the `x()` scale function to give the correct position.

At present this is implemented as a `for` loop for each entry in the `labels` variable. The y origin and endpoint are taken from the data `minY` and `maxY`. A text label is attached to the end of the line.

```
labels = [
 {
  'x':50,
  'label':test'
 }

 var label = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class","ilabel")

// Labels         
for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    labl = labels[i];

    label.append('line')
        .attr('x1', x( labl.x ) )
        .attr('y1', y( maxY ) )
        .attr('x2', x( labl.x ) 
        .attr('y2', y( minY ) )
        .attr("class","ilabel-line");

    label.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" +  x( labl.x )+"," + y( maxY )+ ") rotate(-60)")
            .style("text-anchor", "start")
            .attr("dx", ".5em")              
            .attr("class","ilabel-label")

      .text(labl.label);

}
```

How would I re-write this in a data-driven way i.e. passing the labels in as a `.data` then iterating over this to draw a series of parallel vertical lines.

```
var label = svg.selectAll(".ilabel")
      .data(labels)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class","ilabel")
```

The bit I'm having trouble getting my head around is the `x()` and `y()` functions. `x()` should of course return the x position of the line (which is constant for a given line), but how/what should the y function return to draw a line between two defined points (`minY` & `maxY`).

```
line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
  .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });

label.append('path')
  .attr("d", line)
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `rect` regions instead as shaded areas in preference to lines. However, returning to this I realised that the code is almost the same for drawing a series of rectangles vs. a series of straight lines. The confusion was arising from the d3 function `.line()` which is used to generate a `path`. However you can create a series of straight lines by using `svg:line` and passing data via a generator function (here wrapped in a dictionary):

```
var line = {
    'x1':(function(d) { return x( labl.x ); }),
    'y1':(function(d) { return y( maxY ); }),
    'x2':(function(d) { return x( labl.x ); }),
    'y2':(function(d) { return y( minY) }),
    }


var label = svg.selectAll(".labels")
      .data(labels)
      .enter();

    label.append("svg:line")
            .attr("x1", line.x1)
            .attr("y1", line.y1)
            .attr("x2", line.x2)
            .attr("y2", line.y2)
        .attr("class","label-line");
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just use the axis functions in d3.  Have a look at this example on [Bl.ocks](http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/6579467) you can easily set the ticks using tickValues and then the length of the ticks using innerTickSize and outerTicksize.  You'll also need to set the orientation.

Comment: I didn't opt to use the axis ticks as (as far as I could see) that would alter the position on the scale ticks on the axis too. But thanks for the suggestion, led me onto a solution!