# Rectangles Instead of Ticks D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Similar to question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123788/draw-a-grid-or-rectangles-using-a-scale/19363254?noredirect=1#comment51059096_19363254), I've been working on the same thing as in the last question. My question now is similar to the link, but is more about the implementation. When I run my code, I get an error in my log that says "TypeError: x.ticks is not a function". This is the piece of code it refers to:

```
svg.selectAll("g.grid")
    .data(y.ticks()).enter()
    .append("g").attr("class", "grid")
    .selectAll("rect")
        .data(x.ticks())
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d, i, j) {
                return xScale(j);
        })
         .attr("y", function(d, i, j) {
                return yScale(i);
        })
        .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
        .attr("height", yScale.rangeBand())
         .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
              return ((i) % 2) == 1 ? "green" : "blue";
         });
```

This code works perfectly well in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ny2FJ/16/) fiddle, but gives me an error while running it in my code, as seen [here](http://codepaste.net/ehkara). Any help?

Comment: Works fine for me apart from the legend code: https://jsfiddle.net/ayurgygs/

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I'm not seeing anything?

Comment: You may have to unblock content.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I meant for it to work with the alternating rectangles

Comment: Well you haven't implemented that. My point is that I'm not getting the error you're getting.

Comment: Right, give me a sec to update the code @LarsKotthoff

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Right so, the code I've put in has the code for the ticks and gives me the error, but the jsFiddle you posted doesn't have an error because it doesn't contain the rectangle code. Check with the code in the post please? It may be just me or a typo or something, so would you mind checking?

Comment: Argh, so the code you've posted as your code where the error can be seen doesn't actually contain the code where the error can be seen? Well in that case the answer given is correct -- you can't call `.ticks()` on an ordinal scale.

Comment: Very well. So what is the best solution then?

Comment: Never mind got it thanks @LarsKotthoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you are trying to call ticks on an [ordinal scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales) instead of a [linear scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales). Utilising rangeBoundBands, like in the question you've linked to, is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you're using an ordinal scale. D3 makes you use a linear scale if you want to call .ticks(), otherwise it throws an error

Comment: This isn't quite right, there are also other types of scale that you can call `.tick()` on.